# Why .NET 5 GC doesn't collect (or at least calling Finalize) clearly dereferenced objects?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, roslyn, finalizer

I wanted to test the Garbage Collector and having tough time doing so.

I Written the following trivial test code:

```
using System;

class Foo
{
   int  i;
        
   public Foo(int v)
   {
      i = v;
      Console.WriteLine($"{i} was born");
   }
   ~Foo()
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"{i} has died");
   }
}

public class Program
{
   [STAThread]
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Foo n1 = new Foo(1);
       Foo n2 = new Foo(2);
       Foo n3 = new Foo(3);
       Foo n4 = new Foo(4);
            
       Console.WriteLine("built everything");
       GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true);
       GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        
       n1 = null;
       n2 = null;
       n3 = n4;
            
       Console.WriteLine("deref n1..n3");
       GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true);
       GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
       Console.WriteLine("done.");
   }
}
```

And noticed that under .NET475 nor [.NET5 Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gd2eaq),

> 1 was born
> 2 was born
> 3 was born
> 4 was born
> built everything
> deref n1..n3
> done.

The Garbage collector either don't call my finalizers or not collecting my dereferenced objects entirely.
(Note: The same was going on my machine, without the Online Fiddle)

Interestingly, when trying [Roslyn3.8 Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zLO59w) it seems to work.

> 1 was born
> 2 was born
> 3 was born
> 4 was born
> built everything
> deref n1..n3
> 3 has died
> 2 has died
> 1 has died
> done.

(Note: it even works without all my "FORCE EVERYTHING" to the GC.)

I am in kind of a distrust crisis with the .NET GC at the moment :)
Why is the .NET compiler missing my finalizers? did it even collect my stuff?

Comment: _"I am in kind of a distrust crisis with the .NET GC at the moment"_ -- why? Do you have a **real world** scenario where objects aren't collected when they absolutely need to be? The fact is, there has _never_ been any guarantee that a finalizer would run, nor that any object _will_ be collected. GC has always been on a "advisory" basis. In your example, if you simply move all the object creation code into a separate method, GC works exactly as you want. Likely one of the dozens or hundreds of optimizations made to GC in .NET is responsible for the newer behavior, but it really doesn't matter.

Comment: If you really care, feel free to look through the various changes described here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-5/. Of course, if the change was made in an earlier version, you'll need to review the documented changes for that earlier version instead. I don't see any actual _practical problem_ that needs solving here. It's clearly apparent that, for whatever reason, .NET is treating these objects as still reachable until the current method's stack frame is gone (i.e. the method has returned). There's no rule that says it has to do otherwise.

Comment: Is this debug or release mode?

Comment: [When everything you know is wrong, part one](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/) and [When everything you know is wrong, part two](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/21/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-two/)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: I blame the notion that objects get "collected" for causing a lot of needless confusion.  In many cases, the behavior of the GC is more like that of a bowling-alley pinsetter: it moves everything that needs to be kept to a new location and then clears out storage without knowing or caring how many objects had occupied it.  Finalization is accommodated by inspecting all objects with registered finalizers between the time all strongly-reachable objects are visited and the time storage is cleared out wholesale, so finalizable objects can be made reachable but...

Comment: ...added to a list of objects that had been reachable only via the list of finalizable objects, and consequently need to have their `Finalize` methods run--a process which, far from "collecting" objects, actually prevents the storage used to hold the objects from being reclaimed when it otherwise would have.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with the comments, you should be very careful in trying to understand GC from such examples. You can, just be careful and you really need to understand what you are doing.

Here it's either Debug mode or .NET Core 3.1/.NET 5 default behaviour of JIT Tier0 (*QuickJIT*) - in both scope of objects are prolonged till the method end (or in other words, runtime doesn't care to make it as short as possible). Run it with [Tiered compilation disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/compilation#tiered-compilation) and you will see.

Or add optimization attribute to the `Main` method (which translates to disabling Tier0 for a method):

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ...
```

You can observe this behaviour at the level of JIT-generated code and its corresponding GCInfo (IL level is not enough).

**Not-optimized version (Tier0)** - as you see, results of allocations (`rax` after `JIT_New` calls) are stored on the stack (`rbp-8`, `rbp-10`, `rbp-18` and `rbp-20`). And those stack locations are reported as `Untracked` which in GCInfo nomenclature means *"treated as reachable during the whole method lifetime"*.

```
!U /d -gcinfo 00007ffd4a605ec0
Normal JIT generated code
Finalizers.Program.Main(System.String[])
ilAddr is 0000024B68962050 pImport is 0000020B3E9FF5C0
Begin 00007FFD4A605EC0, size 142

...
Code size: 142
Untracked: +rbp+10 +rbp-8 +rbp-10 +rbp-18 +rbp-20
...
.\Program.cs @ 12:
mov     rcx,7FFD4A6D4D90h (MT: Finalizers.Foo)
call    coreclr!JIT_New (00007ffd`aa0806f0)
mov     qword ptr [rbp-8],rax
...
.\Program.cs @ 13:
mov rcx,7FFD4A6D4D90h (MT: Finalizers.Foo)
call    coreclr!JIT_New (00007ffd`aa0806f0)
mov     qword ptr [rbp-10h],rax
...
.\Program.cs @ 14:
mov rcx,7FFD4A6D4D90h (MT: Finalizers.Foo)
call    coreclr!JIT_New (00007ffd`aa0806f0)
mov     qword ptr [rbp-18h],rax
...
.\Program.cs @ 15:
mov rcx,7FFD4A6D4D90h (MT: Finalizers.Foo)
call    coreclr!JIT_New (00007ffd`aa0806f0)
mov     qword ptr [rbp-20h],rax
...
```

**Optimized (Tier1)** - here as you see results of allocations are indeed discarded (`rax` is overrided from call to call). Moreover, as you can also see, *safepoint*s (places where GC may suspend a thread) are not reporting any roots. And they would, if GCInfo wanted to say that at a given safepoint there is a root in a register.

```
0:007> !U /d -gcinfo 00007ffd4a5e5f20
Normal JIT generated code
Finalizers.Program.Main(System.String[])
ilAddr is 00000151A7672050 pImport is 000001C2D08FF1A0
Begin 00007FFD4A5E5F20, size 1cc

...
.\Program.cs @ 12:
0000003a is a safepoint: 
mov     rcx,7FFD4A6B4240h (MT: Finalizers.Foo)
call    coreclr!JIT_New (00007ffd`aa0806f0)
00000049 is a safepoint: 
mov     rcx,rax
mov     edx,1
call    00007ffd`4a5e5b00 (Finalizers.Foo..ctor(Int32), mdToken: 0000000006000003)
.\Program.cs @ 13:
00000056 is a safepoint: 
mov rcx,7FFD4A6B4240h (MT: Finalizers.Foo)
call    coreclr!JIT_New (00007ffd`aa0806f0)
00000065 is a safepoint: 
mov     rcx,rax
mov     edx,2
call    00007ffd`4a5e5b00 (Finalizers.Foo..ctor(Int32), mdToken: 0000000006000003)

.\Program.cs @ 14:
00000072 is a safepoint: 
mov rcx,7FFD4A6B4240h (MT: Finalizers.Foo)
call    coreclr!JIT_New (00007ffd`aa0806f0)
00000081 is a safepoint: 
mov     rcx,rax
mov     edx,3
call    00007ffd`4a5e5b00 (Finalizers.Foo..ctor(Int32), mdToken: 0000000006000003)

.\Program.cs @ 15:
0000008e is a safepoint: 
mov rcx,7FFD4A6B4240h (MT: Finalizers.Foo)
call    coreclr!JIT_New (00007ffd`aa0806f0)
0000009d is a safepoint: 
mov     rcx,rax
mov     edx,4
call    00007ffd`4a5e5b00 (Finalizers.Foo..ctor(Int32), mdToken: 0000000006000003)
...
```

Comment: _"IL level is not enough to analyze GCInfo"_ -- true. But _if the local doesn't even exist_, the "liveness of locals" is irrelevant. Your post fails to explain why, even in the optimized case where the object reference is immediately discarded, the objects _still_ are not collected and finalized. And that's actually the question that was asked (essentially, though not in so many words).

Comment: Ah, I see. But now there's a different question: why, given that the C# compiler removed the local variables altogether, did the JIT compiler apparently reintroduce them and store the return values for the method? It's one thing to say that the IL doesn't tell the whole story -- that's certainly true -- but it's another thing entirely to find (and say) that the JIT compiler has actually _added_ new code that wasn't even in the IL in the first place, as is the case in the tier 0 code you show above.

Comment: Well, this is indeed a whole different story - in general it's like an old abstraction (stack-based IL code) vs implementation (JITted machine code). Here abstraction leaks, again ¯\_(ツ)_/¯